# Picklist values with some values non - clickable on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a list and i want to display on visualforce page as a dropdown menu with some options greyed out. I am not sure how to make some options non- clickable.

I'd appreciate any useful links or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am assuming that you have already used that list and created a list of type `selectOptions` as this will be used to display the values in the drop down. When creating the  selectoptions list you can mention whether to disable a particular value in the dropdown.

The [selectOption constructor](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) can take 3 arguments (value, label, isDisabled). So you can set the isDisabled to true for whichever values you want to keep it as non-clickable

You can do something like this(I copied this from [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm)):

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
    //set the 3rd argument to true for the values which you want to be disabled.
    options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada',true));
    options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));

    return options;
}

<apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!countries}" title="Choose a country">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
    </apex:selectCheckboxes><br/>
```